# When does ec2 switch between public DNS and public IP?

Tags: dns, ip, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, django

I have an application using Django, in Django config there is a list of `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

The application was working fine with the IP `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list.

It then threw the Django error
`"Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.region.compute.amazonaws.com'. You may need to add 'ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.region.compute.amazonaws.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS."`

Although i can fix this by adding new entry to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, I would like to know how/when the `HTTP_HOST` header switches between IP and DNS forms for AWS EC2.

Ref:
Django `ALLLOWED_HOSTS`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: With your example it doesn't look like it changed at all in format but rather just the contents. Both headers are just DNS names?

Comment: How is EC2 involved in this? Do they provide a proxy / load balancer or something?

Comment: @Seth Django is preventing the DNS form from connecting, but not preventing the IP form from connecting. I have verified that adding the DNS form (ec2-xx-xxxx-xxx.amazonaws.com) to the django ALLOWED_HOSTS resolves the issue. I am curious why change in form happened seemingly randomly

Comment: @grawityI am not too sure, will try to check. I have deployed in an EC2 instance, but there is VPN and some networking setup to allow us to ssh into our VPC instances from company network. Not sure if this might affect

Answer (score 0):

The `Host:` HTTP header is supplied by the client (e.g. web browser or API library), and is usually the exact name that the client was *told* to access – basically, it's taken from the URL.

So if you try to access `http://ec2-xx.amazonaws.com/page.html`, the server will receive:

```
GET /page.html HTTP/1.1
Host: ec2-xx.amazonaws.com
```

Though if there is anything in the middle of the HTTP request – e.g. a reverse proxy, or a HTTP load-balancer – it can override the Host: header with its own.

Comment: funny thing is, I didn't change any of my setup or networking in AWS. So I suppose there is something in AWS backend that changed the HTTP `Host:` header, i.e. "something in the middle" like you mentioned